# PHP Replace text in string

Tags: php

i have a problem.
I want in php to replace all 'blablabla' with 'bla'(because i hate blablabla). Here's my code:

```
<?php
$string = 'Dracula always says BlaBlaBla but says he never says BlaBlaBla';
$result = answer to replace here
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try looking at PHP's documentation? I bet there's an easy solution to find.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: use `str_replace` are tried or searched before enter into SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `srt_replace` function to do that like this :

```
str_replace("BlaBlaBla","bla",$string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I will use it

Comment: okay you are welcome.good luck

Comment: It works Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
str_replace("BlaBlaBla","bla",$string)
```

Also you can find it here in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Terminate with semicolon ;